# Three.js: incorrect light on Three.Geometry + LambertMaterial meshes

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting

I have improved my previous formulation of this question ([previous question version](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93031/three-js-lighting-not-calculating-correctly-on-three-geometry-objects)) with a jsfiddle that uses the most recent build of Three.JS and deomonstrates my Three.Geometry lighting issue.  I couldn't get the dependencies to work in Stack Snippets, but the JSFiddle works:

[JSFIDDLE SHOWING INCORRECT LIGHTING](http://jsfiddle.net/DavidWaughRRRRRRRR/hoadj57w/4/embedded/result/)

[image: JSFiddle]

Notice the incorreectly lit faces on the left (Three.Geometry objects), versus the correctly lit adjoining faces on the right (Three.CubeGeometry).

My light code:

```
hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.6 );
hemiLight.color.setHSL( 0.6, 1, 0.6 );
hemiLight.groundColor.setHSL( 0.095, 1, 0.75 );
hemiLight.position.set( 0, 50, 0 );
app.scene.add( hemiLight );

dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
dirLight.color.setHSL( 0.1, 1, 0.95 );
dirLight.position.set( -1, 1.75, 1 );
dirLight.position.multiplyScalar( 50 );
app.scene.add( dirLight );
```

You can see the JSFiddle source for the THREE.CubeGeometry (mesh 1, 2, 3) and THREE.Geometry (mesh 4, 5, 6) objects.  Mesh 5 and 6 have lambert faces individually instantiated and assigned by array, whereas geo 4 has a single lambert material passed in to the mesh constructor.

Is it possible that the materials in the material-array storage class THREE.MeshFaceMaterial need to be in a particular order for a cube to light properly?  I've assigned them in the order: 2 bottom faces, 8 side faces, 2 top faces.

Why would the light be tiling on the green cubes if the Three.Geometry object appears to be correctly added to the scene?  Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to see the normals of your objects so I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rab3pwpp/ with calls to `Face|Vertex NormalsHelper()`. As you can see the normals are not consistent so the lighting will not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up in case others stumble across this:

While I did re-arrange the vertex order to ensure 90 degree perpendicular normals, I found that didn't make a material difference to adjacent object lighting.

The answer is that three.js doesn't intrinsically calculate lighting across adjacent objects in the scene graph, and while the shadowmap feature attempts to solve this, my investigations showed that a shadowmap solution didn't really work for my use case.

Instead, I applied only 1 of the two geometry calculations to get a simulated light effect

What I had:

```
geo.computeFaceNormals(); 
geo.computeVertexNormals();
```

What I ended up using:

```
geo.computeFaceNormals(); 
//geo.computeVertexNormals();
```

With computeVertexNormals()... 
[image]

Without
[image]

While not a perfect light effect (light is flat), it is workable for now.  Thanks for the help posters.

Answer (score 0):

as answered here:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93031/three-js-lighting-not-calculating-correctly-on-three-geometry-objects/93099#93099

The triangle winding needs to be counter-clockwise as seen from the outside of the object.

To confirm, change all instances of THREE.DoubleSide to THREE.FrontSide and run.  THREE.FrontSide should look perfect because it is the three.js default - but in your example it does not.  Hope this helped! :)